# Dart if(A is B) condition not working properly

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

```dart
          var data = snapshot.data as List;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              var item = data[i];
              print('instance: $item');
              if (item is BookFavorItem) {
                return BookItemCard(
                  bookId: item.bookId,
                  title: item.title,
                  author: item.author,
                );
              } else if (item is BookLentItem) {
                return BookItemCard(
                  bookId: item.bookId,
                  title: item.title,
                  author: item.author,
                  dateRange: '${item.lentDate} - ${item.deadline}',
                );
              } else {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('<$item> not matched'),
                );
              }
            },
          );
```

- Console Output

```sh
I/flutter ( 6832): instance: Instance of 'BookFavorItem'
I/flutter ( 6832): instance: Instance of 'BookFavorItem'
I/flutter ( 6832): instance: Instance of 'BookFavorItem'
I/chatty  ( 6832): uid=10336(com.example.library) 1.ui identical 6 lines
I/flutter ( 6832): instance: Instance of 'BookFavorItem'
I/flutter ( 6832): instance: Instance of 'BookFavorItem'
I/chatty  ( 6832): uid=10336(com.example.library) 1.ui identical 5 lines
I/flutter ( 6832): instance: Instance of 'BookFavorItem'
```

[Screen Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq8Hy.jpg)

As you can see from the code, I got a variable called `item` which is an instance of `BookFavorItem`.

However, when I use condition `if( item is BookFavorItem )` to control the flow, it did not work as expected behavior. (I thought this condition should be true, but it didn't)

The evidence is that I got the message of "Instance of `BookFavorItem`", which is the exact type used for `is` condition from `Debug Console` and `App Screen`

What's wrong with me?

```sh
-> flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264], locale zh-CN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: 1. Don't post code as an image. 2. What evidence do you have that the check is not working?

Comment: @jamesdlin I have updated my question, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You still haven't posted evidence that the `if` check does *not* work.  What makes you say so?  Did you set a breakpoint in the `if (item is BookFavorItem) {` block and not trigger it?  Did you add a `debugPrint` statement in that block and not get any output?  Please explain.

Comment: Of course, I did. I use `print('instance: $item');` to see the exact type from the Debug Console.  Besides, there is also a screen shot showing the type of `item`, which proved that if-statement check failed.

Comment: The existing `print` statement only shows what the type is; it does *not* show which `if` block was actually followed so does not provide evidence to your claim.  Your screenshot does, which I did not see (again, text explanations are better than screenshots).

Comment: As for your problem: is it possible that you have more than one class named `BookFavorItem`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't realised that I had it defined twice.  (Besides, thanks for your advice and I should use more text explanations.)